# Tikz flowchart: center text + math in node

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode, horizontal-alignment

I'm trying to draw a flowchart with TikZ. In one of the decision "diamonds", I have both text and a bit of math between `$`.

```
\node [decision, below of=buildbid, node distance=1.8cm, aspect=8, minimum size=20mm] (evalTotImpact) {$\delta_b\left(b_{\text{cur}},b_{\text{last}}\right)\geq$max?};
```

Unfortunately, despite using `centered` in the tikzstyle definitions, the text position seems to be fixed and ends up outside of the block, as can be seen on this picture.

[image]

It does not happen for other blocks in the flowchart with math...

Here is the smallest example I could make:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\begin{document}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, draw, fill=white, text width=4em, text centered, node distance=3cm, inner sep=0pt, font=\footnotesize]
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=white, text width=6em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=6pt, font=\footnotesize]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex', font=\footnotesize]

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 1.7cm, auto]
\footnotesize
\tikzset{block/.append style={text width=10em, minimum height=2em}}
\node [decision, aspect=8, minimum size=20mm] (evalTotImpact) {$\delta_b\left(b_{\text{cur}},b_{\text{last}}\right)\geq$max?};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Text that is wider than `text width` and can't be wrapped around to a new line will protrude over the right edge, regardless of `align=center` or `text centered`. Do you need all `decision` nodes in your flow chart to be the same size? If not, you could simply remove the `text width` key from your style definition, or disable it locally using `text width={}` in the individual node. If you need to keep the node sizes identical, you could use `label=center:<node text>` to place the text in the node.

Comment: I don't know what do you really want, but I tell you that the problem comes from de `\tikzstyle{decision}...text width=4em`, if you change that value you will see that it works well. But as I said, I don't know what do you exactly want. Well, Jake wrote faster (and better) than me.

Comment: They can be different sizes. I have disabled it locally as you suggested, and that solves it.
It seems that I'm not fully understanding the impact of specifying `text width`. I thought it was directly related to the font width.

Comment: @KlaasDC: `text width` is used to tell TikZ to pretend that the width of the text in a node is whatever you specify, instead of actually measuring the width of the text. Together with `text height` and `text depth`, this can be used to achieve fixed node sizes, unlike `minimum height` and `minimum width`, which merely set lower limits: In that case, the text dimensions are still measured and used to increase the node size if necessary.

Comment: @Jake: I see, thank you for the explanation! But (a bit unrelated to the question), what is then the best way to exactly specify font sizes in the node?

Comment: @KlaasDC: `text width` and `text height` has nothing to do with the font size, but with the total width and height of a piece of text. To change the font size, you can use `font=\small` (or `\scriptsize`, or `\Large`, or `\textbf`, or any of the other switches that you can also use in "normal" text).

Comment: @Jack: `font=\bfseries` is better than `font=\textbf`!

Comment: @PaulGaborit: Oops, that's what I meant of course! As a matter of fact, not only is `\bfseries` better than `\textbf`, but `\textbf` doesn't work at all. (By the way, I don't get a comment notification if you mistype my user name `=)`)

Answer (score 3):

Text that is wider than `text width` which can't be wrapped around to a new line will protrude over the right edge, regardless of `align=center` or `text centered`.

If you don't need all nodes to have the same size, you could simply remove the `text width` key from your style definition, or disable it locally using `text width={}` in the individual node. If you need to keep the node sizes identical, you could use `label=center:<node text>` to place the text in the node.